# How to publish a redesigned application on the stores

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

I'm working on the app about three years ago and it was published on

- App store
- Google play
- App Gallery

Now I want to change the whole app UI/UX

is it acceptable in the app stores to upload a whole re-designed app?

P.S. I read the app store policies and they didn't mention anything about publish redesigning an already published application

Comment: It's your app. You can do what you like. Just use the same bundle name (and Google Play equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

> is it acceptable in the app stores to upload a whole re-designed app?

Yes, For Huawei AppGallery, if you want to change the whole app UI/UX then uploading a whole re-designed app, you need to apply to remove the app from HUAWEI AppGallery. After an app is removed from sale, users will not be able to find the app on AppGallery and the app version in AppGallery Connect changes to the Draft state. If you want to release the app again, edit the app version in Draft state and release the edited version.

For Details ,check [this Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-removeapp-0000001100316676).

**How to upload a whole re-designed app?**

Follow the normal application update process is fine. You can follow this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-updateappinfo-0000001100156682).